# Кастомная авторизация в ASP.net Blazor не работает

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Доброго времени суток.

Делал свою авторизацию для веб приложения на ASP.NET Blazor и столкнулся с проблемой.

Работает/не работает это сейчас так:

1. пользователь вводит логин/пароль;
2. мы ищем в БД такую пару. Если нет, то ничего, просто пишем пользователю что он не залогинился. Если есть - переадресовываем его на index, а в куки даём ему уникальный ключик, с которым ассоциируем его уровень доступа;
3. при каждом GET запросе берём этот ключик, и сравниваем с сохранёнными активными сессиями, и если есть сессия с таким ключом то определяем по нему уровень доступа и сохраняем его в Singleton такого вида:

```
public class AppData
{
   public string user { get; set; }
   public DBUser currentUser { get; set; }
}
```

Вот такой GET запрос:

```
public void OnGet() {
            var userId = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["user"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) {
                userId = -1 + "";
            }

            appData.user = userId;
            appData.currentUser = UsersHandler.getUserFromCacheById(userId);
            DBHandler.errors.Add("get as " + appData.currentUser.login);
        }
```

Если нет такой сохранённой сессии, то отправляем пользователя на шаг 1;

4. при нажатии кнопки разлогиниться - удаляем сессию.

Может я конечно изобрёл дурь какую, прошу сильно не ругать. Но мне очень хотелось использовать существующую таблицу с пользователями.

А теперь собственно в чём сама проблема.
Оказалось что GET запрос отправляется не при каждом переходе между страницами, а только когда нажимается кнопка "обновить", или открывается ранее не открывавшаяся страница. Видимо так экономятся ресурсы сервера. Но из за этого у меня возникает ситуация, когда пользователь u1 зашёл с ролью r1, а пользователь  u2 зашёл как r2. После того как, например u1 перейдёт на другую страницу с выполнением GET запроса, обновив currentUser и user в AppData, у u2, пока тот не отправит GET запрос, всё выглядит так, будто роль у него не r2, а r1.

У меня была идея отправлять GET запросы при любой перезагрузке страницы, но я не нашёл способа. Ну да и выглядит это как костыль. Здорово было бы иметь возможность хранить для каждой сессии экземпляр DBUser в отдельном месте. Но я совершенно не понимаю как этого добиться.

Я сперва думал что singleton сервис для каждой сессии свой, оказалось что он общий на всё приложение. То же самое со static классами.

Есть вообще в приложении такое место где бы можно было хранить, для каждого пользователя свой экземпляр класса DBUser, ну или хотя-бы как string ключ user?

Я даже доступ к куки могу получить только в GET запросе, или через IJSRuntime, но уже после отрисовки. А после отрисовки он мне уже не нужен...

У меня уже нет никаких идей, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `А теперь собственно в чём сама проблема. Оказалось что GET запрос отправляется не при каждом переходе между страницами, а только когда нажимается кнопка "обновить", или открывается ранее не открывавшаяся страница.` - вы сами понимаете, как ваше приложение работает? Вы создаете single page application? В обычном веб приложении каждая новая страница является результатом get запроса.

Comment: Вместо изобретения велосипеда, поглядите как можно стандартные поставшики переопределить, может вам это подойдет  [Пользовательские поставщики хранилища для ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @tym32167 Я делаю приложение на server side Blazor. Насколько я выяснил get запрос отправляется в тех случаях что я описал. В остальных просто вызывается перерисовка модулей, где случились события.

Да это и не важно. Факт в том, что нет, не каждый раз вызывается GET запрос.

Comment: @tym32167 "Вместо изобретения велосипеда, поглядите как можно стандартные поставшики переопределить, может вам это подойдет" - я, конечно рассматриваю такой вариант. Но в настоящий момент если я бы мог просто сохранить один маленький экземпляр класса DBUser это решило бы все мои проблемы. Я уверен что как-то можно его сохранить свой, для каждого подключения, просто я не понимаю как.

Comment: [Управление сеансами и состояниями в ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо tym32167 за подсказку.

**Всё нижесказанное относится только к ServerSide Blazor. Для WebAssembly, по приведённой ниже ссылке, есть соответствующая инструкция.**

Мне удалось найти способ хранить ключ пользователя для каждого пользователя отдельно. Реализовал я это с помощью [ProtectedSessionStorage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#server-side-storage-server) и каскадных параметров.

Сперва я создал компонент - поставщик ключа сессии пользователя (**CommonVariablesComponent.razor**).

Его содержимое:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage ProtectedLocalStorage

@if (isLoaded)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="this">
        @ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
}
else
{
    <LoaderAnimation/>
}

@code {
    private bool isLoaded = false;

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public string currentUserToken { get; set; }

    public async Task setCurrentUser(DBUser user)
    {
        currentUserToken = user.identificator;
        await SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string> tokenResult = await ProtectedLocalStorage.GetAsync<string>("token");
        currentUserToken = tokenResult.Success ? tokenResult.Value : "-1";
        isLoaded = true;
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await ProtectedLocalStorage.SetAsync("token", currentUserToken);
    }
}
```

> Важным нюансом, чтобы это всё работало является то, что нужно
> отключить пререндер в приложении заменив в _Hosts.cshtml
>
> ```
> <app>
>        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
> </app>
> ```
>
> на
>
> ```
> <app>
>         <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
> </app>
> ```
>
> Это позволит использовать interop в методе OnInitialized(), что необходимо здесь, для
> ProtectedSessionStorage, и чего мне так не
> хватало для сохранения ключа в Cookies.
>
> Тем не менее я остановился именно на ProtectedSessionStorage,
> отказавшись от Cookies, т.к. оно предоставляет шифрование данных из
> коробки, что лишает нас риска того, что пользователь напрямую считает
> наши данные.

Далее мы в компонент **CommonVariablesComponent** оборачиваем следующим образом всё наше приложение в **App.razor**:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CommonVariablesComponent>
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </CommonVariablesComponent>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CommonVariablesComponent>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Неправильная ссылка.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CommonVariablesComponent>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Таким образом передавая Value во все вложенные компоненты. В Value, как видно выше, мы передаём ссылку на компонент **CommonVariablesComponent**, таким образом информируя вложенные компоненты о всех публичных полях и методах этого компонента. В.т.ч. о поле **currentUserToken**, к которому мы теперь можем получить доступ из любой точки приложения, обратившись к **CommonVariablesComponent** как к каскадному параметру:

```
[CascadingParameter] private CommonVariablesComponent CommonVariables { get; set; }
```

и дальше я делаю то о чём мечтал - достаю текущего пользователя по его токену/ключу:

```
currentUser = UsersHandler.getUserFromCacheById(CommonVariables.currentUserToken);
```

В общем свой велосипед я доделал. И им вполне доволен. Спасибо всем.